# how to write distinct and count query in cakephp using find

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How to write below query in cakephp using find .

```
$this->tmp_sale->query("select  DISTINCT COUNT( tax ) as 'tax_amount' , SUM( quantity ) as 'quantity1',tax,tax_amount1 from tmp_sale where employee='$emp' and no ='$no' and store='$store_name' group by tax");
```

Comment: Please don`t do "tag spam" or do you really expect an answer for *three* versions of the framework while you show zero effort in solving the problem yourself? Hint: Read the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do a find 'all' on the TmpSale model and define the fields for the COUNT and SUM:-

```
$data = $this->TmpSale->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'COUNT(tax) AS tax_amount',
            'SUM(quantity) AS quantity1',
            'tax',
            'tax_amount1'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'employee' => $emp,
            'no' => $no,
            'store' => $store_name
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'tax'
        )
    )
);
debug($data);
```

I've included a debug($data) at the end as you'll probably want to take a look at the array returned as it will perhaps not be in the format you'd expect due to the COUNT and SUM fields.